# Who are the antagonists in the Waterworld books and comics?

Tags: waterworld

Deacon, Nord and the Smokers are the antagonists in the Waterworld film, Who are the antagonists in the Waterworld books and comics?

Comment: https://www.mycomicshop.com/search?TID=162551 some dude called Leviathan in the comics.

Answer (score 4):

**Videogame [Gamespot Review - WaterWorld](https://www.gamespot.com/reviews/waterworld-review/1900-2531843/):**

- Antagonists - Smokers

**Novelization (Max Allan Collins) [Amazon Listing - Waterworld (novel)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Waterworld-Novel-Max-Allan-Collins/dp/1572970014)**

Antagonists - Presumably the Smokers again as the novel is a direct novelization of the film with a bit of "fleshing out".

**Comics (Chris Golden/Tom Sneigoski - Acclaim Comics)**

Antagonists - Various sea creatures (Sharks/Whalefins) and Leviathan:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't place links to copyright infringing sites

Comment: @Snow this is awesome. Thank you.

Comment: Wikipedia and Google - it wasn’t that hard...